# LA Noire with cheats / no combat?

Tags: la-noire

Is there any way to play LA Noire without having to go through fighting and shooting? I really like detective stories and having to murder 20 people in a shoot out kinda ruins it for me. Looking for a mod or a god-mode cheat. Thanks.

Comment: Have you actually played the game? Doesn't the game allow you to skip action sequences after a few failed attempts?

Comment: @deutschZuid It does

Comment: @deutschZuid Still, considering the set save points and, as far as I can tell, unskippable cutscenes, I'd be annoyed at having to reload my last save a few times in just about every case.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to do this. The closest you can get is the game giving the option to skip an action sequence after a few failed attempt.

Comment: I know there isn't any way to do it, I'm looking for a hack or a cheat / mod

Comment: You did not say that in the original question and now you've changed the question completely. You also did not mention you were playing on PC.

Comment: I did say it originally but someone else edited my comment to remove the relevant information, I have no idea why. I just restored my original version.

Comment: He changed probably to avoid the question being tagged as a mod recommendation question, which is considered offtopic here. So by reverting back to your original version, you've made the issue relevant again unfortunately.